# LOOKUP on dynamic sheet names

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do the following:

```
=LOOKUP(C2,D2!A:A,D2!B:B)
```

where D2='sheet2' in text

instead of

```
=LOOKUP(C2,'sheet2'!A:A,'sheet2'!B:B)
```

How do I do this? D2's value will change depending on the row in my spreadsheet.

Comment: Did you find anything here worth accepting? It is always good for SO users closing questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `INDIRECT`. To avoid issues with sheet names having spaces, a good option is

```
=LOOKUP(C2,INDIRECT("'"&D2&"'"&"!A:A"),INDIRECT("'"&D2&"'"&"!B:B"))
```

and always excluding quotes from cells bearing sheet names (e.g., `D2=sheet2` instead of `D2='sheet2'`). There may still be issues when sheet names have quotes themselves.